# What happens when you request 8G of RAM on a machine with 4GB of physical memory?

Tags: operating-system

Is the operating system 32-bit, or 64-bit?
Will the 8G of memory be used after application?
Does the operating system use the Swap mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac when I was running ipfs, was using 26Gb's and the system only had 16Gb available, so it did create some swap but not nearly enough to meet the demand of the application (I presume there was a bug, and filed an issue.) I think it just doesn't exist or at least in the case of ifs it didn't.
[Activity Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlXgv.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To a first approximation, a 32-bit OS can't address more than 4GB of RAM, so in general this question wouldn't come up when running a 32-bit OS.  (There are [some work-arounds in some OS](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090706-00/?p=17623#:%7E:text=No)'s, but they are kind of hackish and in most cases you're better off just using a 64-bit OS if you need to work with that much data in RAM at once).

Address-space issues aside, on most OS's if you try to use more memory than is physically available, the OS will start using swap space on a disk to temporarily hold "extra" pages that can't fit in RAM directly.  Of course this will only work if swap space has been set up, and it will usually be painfully slow, so most people try to avoid using that feature unless they are really patient and/or strapped for cash.

Note that most modern OS's use *optimistic allocation*, which is to say that when a program requests RAM, the OS returns a pointer to the allocated region in the virtual address space, but doesn't actually allocate any physical pages of RAM at that time.  Then, when the program tries to actually read or write to a page of that RAM, the MMU will generate a page-fault, and the OS will step in at the last moment to supply a page of physical RAM to hold the data that the program is trying to store there.  This is considered useful because many programs request more RAM than they actually use, and this allows the OS to stretch its physical RAM budget by only allocating physical RAM when it is actually needed for something.  The downside of this is that it becomes very difficult to handle hard out-of-memory errors (e.g. when the computer has run out of both physical RAM *and* swap space), because as far as the program knows, the memory-allocation has already succeeded, and all it is trying to do is read or write to the allocated memory.  Since there's no error-handling mechanism for that, in most case the OS will simply kill the program in case of memory-exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the operating system 32-bit, or 64-bit?

It depends. For 32-bit it's likely that the program is limited to (less than) 4 GiB of virtual space; however there are ways to allocate more physical memory and map part of it at a time into the virtual address space (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/address-windowing-extensions ); so without knowing how the memory was requested there's no way to know if the OS is 32-bit or 64-bit.

> Will the 8G of memory be used after application?

There's no way to guess if the 8 GB of physical memory will be used by the application, and no way to guess if it the physical memory will actually be allocated. For 64-bit; most operating systems will just allocate "virtual space full of zeros" (and no physical memory) until the application tries to modify the contents, and will allocate small pieces (e.g. maybe 4 KiB or maybe 2 MiB pieces) of physical RAM when a small piece is modified.

> Does the operating system use the Swap mechanism?

It depends on how you request the RAM, how much RAM there is (e.g. a "32-bit only" CPU can support up to 16 GiB of RAM via. a CPU feature called Physical Address Extensions), and various other things (e.g. if the memory is actually used/modified, if the OS has any swap space, if the OS has an "OOM killer", if there's some kind of "max. memory per process" quota, etc). For a simple example, when you request 8 GB the request could simply be denied (return a "no memory" error).